# Where to store IPFS hash other than infura.io without paying

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, ipfs

I used infura.io to store IPFS hash few months ago in my Ethereum dapp based on React JS but now it's not free anymore and it is asking for my bank account details. I want to use it for small personal project and don't want to risk adding bank account details for storing IPFS hash.

Comment: As this question is unrelated to programming, a better forum for asking this question would be [ethereum.stackexchange.com](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to host a website you can use https://dappling.network